# How to customize the "Attribute not found" error?

Tags: genexus

I'm working on genexus 17U6 with wwp. When I don't insert an attribute that refers to another transaction, the error "Not found 'CODART' (for example) appears below it, but Codart is the name of the attribute in the table and it is often not understandable. The attribute in question has a description, title, column title and contextual title set but they are not displayed anyway.

How can I change the error message to make it more understandable? I'm searching in the language object but I can't found a way

Answer (score 0):

I think the RefMsg rule comes in handy. This rule allows you to customize the messages when the "Referential Integrity" fails.

Let's assume you have two transactions, "Articulo" and "Factura" and they are tied by the "CodArt" in a 1-n relationship. So, when you're inserting an "Articulo" in your "Invoice" that doesn't exists, the "Not found 'CODART'" message appears.
In this scenario, you have tu put a rule in the "Invoice" transaction like this:

RefMsg('Ingrese un codigo de articulo valido', CodArt);

Thats it.

You can check the wiki for more information [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6865,Refmsg%20rule)